# Connection failed no phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Segue o código amigos:

```
<?php

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
 Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");

 $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

 require 'phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $Mailer = new PHPMailer();
 $Mailer->IsSMTP();
 $Mailer->isHTML(true);
 $Mailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';
 $Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
 $Mailer->SMTPDebug = false;
 $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $Mailer->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
 $Mailer->Port = 587;
 $Mailer->Username = 'fakes@hotmail.com';
 $Mailer->Password = 'fakes'; 
 $Mailer->From = 'fakes@hotmail.com';
 $Mailer->FromName = 'Seu Nome';
 $Mailer->Subject = 'Teste';
 $Mailer->Body = 'Mensagem em HTML';
 $Mailer->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto';
 $Mailer->AddAddress('meu_amigo@dominio.com');

 if ($Mailer->Send())
 {
 echo "Enviado com sucesso";
 }
 else 
 {
 echo json_encode($Mailer->SMTPDebug);
 }
```

Amigos, to tentando fzr o envio de email com esse código, ms smp retorna um erro. Segue os erros:

Ao tentar com debug 1 e 4 respectivamente:

```
"2017-04-25 17:03:06    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
 2017-04-25 17:03:06    SMTP connect() failed. 
 https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
 1"

"2017-04-25 17:04:05    Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.live.com:587, 
timeout=300, options=array (
                                  )
 2017-04-25 17:04:05    Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): 
 SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
                                  error:140770FC:SSL 
 routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol 
 [C:\xampp\htdocs\marcelo\www\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.smtp.php line 294]
 2017-04-25 17:04:05    Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): 
 Failed to enable crypto 
 [C:\xampp\htdocs\marcelo\www\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.smtp.php line 294]
 2017-04-25 17:04:05    Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): 
 unable to connect to ssl://smtp.live.com:587 (Unknown error) 
 [C:\xampp\htdocs\marcelo\www\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.smtp.php line 294]
 2017-04-25 17:04:05    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
 2017-04-25 17:04:05    SMTP connect() failed. 
 https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
 4"
```

Detalhes*
extension=php_openssl.dll está ativo no php.ini e o pop liberado no e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o Live usa TLS e não SSL, basta trocar isto:

```
 $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $Mailer->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
 $Mailer->Port = 587;
```

Por isto:

```
 $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
 $Mailer->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
 $Mailer->Port = 587;
```

Comment: Na vdd seria $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; n?
Msm com a alteração, retorna a mensagem "You must provide at least one recipient email address"

Comment: @hisoka este erro é outro erro, basta traduzir a mensagem para entender o que falta *"Você deve prover pelo menos um email destinatário"*, ou seja você deve ter removido a linha com a função `$mail->AddAddress('meu_amigo@dominio.com');`

Comment: Msm com o AddAddress la mano, ele retorna essa msg. Começou essa msg ontem, dps q eu add o tls. Imagino q seja somente 1 detalhe..

Comment: @hisoka acabei de testar teu script com a ultima versão do phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v5.2.23 e funcionou perfeitamente, veja: https://pastebin.com/cNx12AVH ... tente ver se o phpmailer esta desatualizado se estiver OK teste o script que lhe enviei.

Comment: Desculpa a demora cara.. Resolvi usando o Laravel. Obgd pela ajuda.