# SMTP class PHPmailer

Tags: php

Olá boa tarde estou enfrentado o seguinte erro com a classe PHPMailer , alguém pode me dizer o que posso fazer para resolver ? Obrigado pelo espaço e atenção. !!!

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta class
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

try {
     $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
     $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
     $mail->Username = 'usuario@outlook.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
     $mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

     //Define o remetente
     // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
     $mail->SetFrom('usuario@outlook.com', 'Caio'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->AddReplyTo('usuario@outlook.com', 'Caio'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->Subject = 'Testando';//Assunto do e-mail


     //Define os destinatário(s)
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     $mail->AddAddress('usuario@outlook.com', 'Teste Locaweb');

     //Campos abaixo são opcionais 
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     //$mail->AddCC('destinarario@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario'); // Copia
     //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_oculto@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta
     //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // Adicionar um anexo


     //Define o corpo do email
     $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 

     ////Caso queira colocar o conteudo de um arquivo utilize o método abaixo ao invés da mensagem no corpo do e-mail.
     //$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('arquivo.html'));

     $mail->Send();
     echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso</p>\n";

    //caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
    }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="enviar.php" name="form" method="post" >

                    <h1>Entre em contato</h1>

                    <p class="nome">
                        <input type="text" id="nomeid" placeholder="Nome Completo"  required="required" name="nome" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="fone">
                        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone" id="txttelefone" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[\s][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,5}" placeholder="Telefone" required="required"/>     
                        <script type="text/javascript"> $("#txttelefone").mask("(00) 0000-00000")</script>          
                    </p>

                    <p class="email">
                       <input type="email"  id="email" value="" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Digite Seu E-mail"/>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                       <textarea placeholder="Deixe sua Mensagem" required="required" name="mensagem"></textarea>
                    </p>

                    <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" onclick="Enviar();" value="Enviar" name="enviar" formmethod="POST" />
                    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: "Não foi possível autenticar."

Comment: Falta o TLS e o endereço de SMTP talvez esteja incorreto. Não tenho certeza. Teste essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/200541/3635